# WebView Maximum Cache Size on Android 4.4

Tags: android, caching, webview, chromium, android-4.4-kitkat

On Android 4.4, Webview is based on Chromium. After checking the code, it seems the maxmium cache size is hard-coded to 10MB in\src\android_webview\browser\net\aw_url_request_context_getter.cc.

Since I'm new to the Chromium source code, is this the correct place where the maximum cache size is defined, or may in other place ?

I'm asking here because it seems the value is hard-coded to 20M on previous Android WebView version (4.0 later) in \Source\WebKit\android\WebCoreSupport\WebCache.cpp

Does anyone know why it is reduced to 10M in Android 4.4?

Thank you

BRs

Comment: This issue reported (probably by you) and assigned as a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323871. I suggest that answer yourself here, for future questions. tnx